# 5 Pins soldered from a USB 2.0 type A cable

Tags: pcb, usb, soldering

I have just recived a new product and I want to replace the permanent USB cable that is soldered to the board with a shorter female end USB. The problem is that when I disassembled the item I saw that the cable is soldered to 5 points to the board using 5 cables that come out of it. Now as far as I know USB 2.0 Type A has only 4 pins (Voltage, Data-, Data+ & GND).

How can I then connect it (The 4 pin female end USB) and why does it have 5 pins when on the other end were it connects to the computer it is a type A connector.

[image: The board]

Comment: One of them is the cable shield.

Comment: The 5th one could be the shield. If you have a multimeter then you can check if one of them is connected the outer metal case of the Type-A connector.

Answer (score 2):

Since the product came with standard USB type A plug, the fifth wire would be connected to the metal chassis frame shield of the connector.

Comment: But why? Is it how to OTG works?

Comment: No, USB-A has no OTG. Standard USB will have five conductors between connectors, VCC, D-, D+, GND, and shield.

Comment: So why is there a connection to the shield? What is its purpose?

Comment: That would be another question, but in short, to connect the metal cases of two devices first to equalize their potential, so that there is no electrostatic discharge from data or power pins, and then the shield prevents electromagnetic radiation from affecting the data bus and also prevents the data bus from transmitting electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: @Twins96, why would you bring "OTG"? How it is difficult to get a DMM and verify/check all connections?

Answer (score 0):

The 5th pin is the ID (or "sense") pin.

Look [HERE](https://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/micro_usb_pinout.shtml).

It's purpose is to select which device is host and which is slave.  This is often called OTG or On-The-Go.

Here is an example.  The type-A connector is on the right.

[image]

Comment: There's no ID pin on a Type-A plug. The OP states that the cable has a Type-A connector, not a Type-B micro.

Comment: That is expected for OTG, yes.  Please see the diagram I added.

Comment: OK, but if it is connected to the board then were is it conncted to at the other end were the USB connector is?

Comment: Almost surely connected to the ground pin, at the connector itself.

Comment: Check it with an ohmmeter to be convinced.

Comment: Thank you a lot :-)

Comment: This topic has nothing to do with OTG, it was a leap of imagination from OP. I would suggest to remove this answer.